# Capitalize first character of first string, first two characters of second string,

Tags: python

I have a list as follows:

```
days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday']
```

and I want to `print` this:

```
Monday     # 1 uppercase letter
TUesday    # 2 uppercase letters
WEDnesday  # ...
THURsday
```

This is what I have so far:

```
for day in days:
    print day[0].upper() = day[1:]
```

which prints:

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
```

How can I get the desired result?

Comment: Thank you, Ev.Kounis for the edit.

Comment: You probably meant `print day[0].upper() + day[1:]`, right? The `=` seems to be a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You could have tried a bit harder since you were getting close. Take a look at this:

```
days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday']

for i, day in enumerate(days):
    print(day[:i+1].upper() + day[i+1:])
```

Or simply:

```
print('\n'.join([x[:i+1].upper() + x[i+1:] for i, x in enumerate(days)]))
```

They both `print` the desired:

```
Monday
TUesday
WEDnesday
THURsday
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable in python, so you have to create a new one:

```
list_1 = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday']
list_2 = []

for i, day in enumerate(list_1):
    list_2.append(day[:i+1].upper() + day[i+1:].lower())

print(list_2)
```

You could use the same list, I used a different one to illustrate that they are different strings.

Output:

```
['Monday', 'TUesday', 'WEDnesday', 'THURsday']
```

Comment: Thank you, Jose A.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday']

number = 1
for day in days:
    print(day[:number].upper()+day[number:])
    number +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also try this:

```
days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday']

result = [day[:i].upper() + day[i:] for day, i in zip(days, range(1, len(days) + 1))]

print('\n'.join(result))
# Monday
# TUesday
# WEDnesday
# THURsday
```